# I can't solve this "parsererror" ajax error

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am currently doing ajax with django.
However, the response throws an error.

I send a request to the views using ajax and create a model. 
And now we ’re ready to create.
I think there is a problem with the return of views.

The error message I get

```
fail 200
(index):150 parsererror
(index):151 SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at Ut (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

The javascript code (jquery)

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
            let $submit_input = $(this).find('input')
            let $data = $(this).data('group')
            console.log($data);

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                'url': "{% url 'groups:ajax_post_add' %}",
                'type': 'POST',
                'data': {
                    'group': $data,
                     csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                },
                'dataType': 'json',
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            $submit_input.attr('disabled', true);
            }
          }).then((...args) => { // done
    const [data, textStatus, jqXHR] = args;

    console.log('done', jqXHR.status);
  })
  .catch((...args) => { // fail
    const [jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown] = args;

    console.log('fail', jqXHR.status);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
  })
        });
```

The python code

```
#views
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def GroupRequestAdd(request):
    group_id = request.POST.get('group')
    group_id = group.objects.get(id=group_id)
    request_add = belong.objects.create(user=request.user,group=group_id)
    return HttpResponse("ajax is done!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short you are returning a string of text from your django view which is not a valid JSON string; therefore your javascript cannot parse it as "valid" json.

The offending line is `return HttpResponse("ajax is done!")`. Instead change this to return json.

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'status': 'ajax is done!'}))
```

Or, modify your jquery to handle html. This an be done by changing the line: `'dataType': 'json',` to be `'dataType': 'html',`.

Answer (score 1):

The unexpected token you receive is coming from your python script.

> Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0

So it says, that the `token` on position `0` is an `a` and is not valid JSON.
Looking at your code, you could see that that is correct since you return a `string`.

```
return HttpResponse("ajax is done!") // a is your unexpected token at position 0
```

The `dataType` property in `$.ajax` says to the AJAX function what kind of value to expect in the response from the server. In this case you are expecting `JSON` but receive a `string`. So the `$.ajax` function tries to parse the result from JSON but fails.

Change the `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'html'` or `dataType: 'text'` and it will output your response correctly.

Check out the [documentation of jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on how to use the `dataType` property.

Comment: Thank you for the genius answer.
That was a really big help.
I will use it.